# Terminal input does not wrap correctly, or at all

Tags: command-line, bash

For a while now, I've had this persistent issue on all my terminals, from the gnome default and tilda which I both use to ones I just gave a quick whirl, where my input will overwrite the start of its own line when it should wrap, and only wrapping on the next line.

Pressing Ctrl-A to return to the start of the line will instead return me somewhere up in the line before my first input line, from which any more input just gets very weird.

Because this is a really bad explanation and hard to visualize, here's how it looks:

[image: Screencap: line wrapping test]

Does anyone know what this is? It doesn't only happen under certain circumstances, it's a permanent thing that is always there from start to finish of every session in every terminal emulator.

Output of `printf "%s\n" "$PS1" "$COLUMNS"`:

```
leod:~$ printf "%s\n" "$PS1" "$COLUMNS"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ 
80
```

Output of `stty -a`:

```
leod:~$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 11; columns 140; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Comment: Add the output of `printf "%s\n" "$PS1" "$COLUMNS"`, please.

Comment: It could be your program `test` leaves the terminal in an unstable state. If it's a script can you include that in your question? What happens if you start typing without running `test` first, does text wrap normally?

Comment: Added the output for that @muru.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix As my question states, this is a universal thing regardless of what commands are run, including if none are run at all, beforehand. The `test` command being run is just the one that comes with ubuntu, it simply returns false without parameters and does nothing else.

Comment: Can we see the output of `stty -a` as well please?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah, `test` is a shell builtin. It shouldn't affect the terminal at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm in trouble then because I created lots of files named `test`. For example: `$ whereis test` results in: `test: /usr/bin/test /bin/test /home/rick/bin/test /mnt/e/bin/test /usr/share/man/man1/test.1.gz`. At least one of them: `$ ll /mnt/e/bin/test` is an executable at the top of the $PATH: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 rick rick 3661 Nov 11 06:39 /mnt/e/bin/test*`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix wrong test (pun intended). Try `type -a test` instead.

Comment: @muru The shell is at the top of the list so my system should be stable: 1) `$ type -a test` 2) `test is a shell builtin` 3) `test is /mnt/e/bin/test` 4) `test is /usr/bin/test
`. Initially I was worried by: 1) `$ which test` 2) `/mnt/e/bin/test`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This is why `which` sucks. Always use `type`. BTW `type -P` has the same functionality as `which`.

Comment: @steeldriver Added stty -a. I'm guessing that eol being undefined might be the issue?

Comment: @leod Try running `echo $COLUMNS` and compare with the number of columns from `stty -a`.

Comment: @WJAndrea They are the same and stay the same even when resizing the terminal.

Comment: They aren't the same in the original post because I had the terminal fullscreen when running `stty -a`, in case you're wondering.

Comment: have you tried `reset` in the terminal ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl Yes, no change, as one might expect when this is a constant issue from boot.

Comment: What's the output of `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"`? There might be raw escape sequences inside PS1, and `%s` leaves them intact (which might e.g. change the color back and forth which remains unnoticed in the output). `%q` quotes every nonprintable character in a readable way.

Comment: @egmont `$'​​​​​​​​​​\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ '`

Comment: Tadaa... what the heck are those `\b`'s? I mean those are backspaces, but why? Get rid of them.

Comment: @egmont I don't know how or where those came from. I tried changing the PS1 variable in my .bashrc to just the string "test" and it properly changed the user string in my terminal, but `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"` then just output `$'​​​​​​​​​​\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\btest'`, which leaves me a little stumped because PS1 is never touched after that to my knowledge.

Comment: Are these still prepended if you set PS1 in the _last_ line of `.bashrc`?

Comment: @egmont Nope, problem solved! I've no clue how that fixed it, since the only thing that came after were predefined (as in, Ubuntu came with them) aliases for `ls` and attempts to import files that don't exist (an alias file and a completion file), but I'll take the victory here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it worked! I'd be really curious what the actual problem was, if you feel like further debugging, e.g. moving this line up one by one to see where it breaks, or maybe share your broken vs. correct .bashrc with us...

Comment: @egmont Broken: https://ghostbin.com/paste/jdp2t/raw  Functioning: https://ghostbin.com/paste/cox9x/raw

It's a rather large chunk I moved down, since it's all PS1 related.

Comment: It's hard to tell, I think you should try intermediate versions to narrow down the problem. E.g. does sourcing `~/.bash_aliases` mess with your PS1 perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible your terminal is not recognizing the window size correctly. I found a [related question in U&L Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly), and someone suggested the below way of checking whether this is what's going on:

Type

```
shopt | grep checkwinsize
```

If the output is not:

```
checkwinsize    on
```

You can use

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

to activate. To deactivate: `shopt -u checkwinsize`

Comment: Perhaps I didn't test enough but my `checkwinsize` was already `on`. I used `shopt -u checkwinsize` to turn it off and my terminal still wrapped text correctly. I'm not sure if this answer truly solves OP problem.

Comment: Brilliant.  This is the fix I needed.  The command line wrap works perfectly now at well over 80 characters.

Comment: @Randy Glad to hear it worked for you!